# Can't sing high or project

Tags: voice, voice-training

So I have a bit of a problem. Anytime I try to sing higher than I normally can do without going out of tune, my voice will crack and then stop. Like no sound will come out and I'm only exhaling. I've been trying really hard with vocal exercises and warm-ups but nothing is working. I also have trouble with projecting my voice to where I can sing loud and strong. Anytime I try to sing with chest voice, my voice becomes very lazy and loose sounding. Like I can't hold a tune and I struggle to sing on key. It's gotten a little better with practice but it's still not good. I need some tips and help because I really love singing and I'd love to be able to get over this little bump in the road. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to find a good singing teacher with whom you could have lessons? Very often these things are very unique to the individual and a knowledgeable someone who is there to be able to hear (and see) you sing will be infinitely more helpful than the folks on the internet.

Comment: Sounds a lot like what happens when you don't use your diaphragm well. Best bet, get a teacher as @GoatsWearHats said

Comment: @GoatsWearHats  I don't have enough money to get a teacher since I'm using it for a foreign language tutor. Are there any cheap or free videos or lessons that teach how to use your diaphragm better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lottee: This may help get you started with exploring the many voice lessons and tips available on Youtube. Click here to go to [a good voice lesson on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbeXH94qIs0) (BTW, she discusses voice-cracking beginning at the 8 minute mark.) If numbers mean anything to you, this teacher's one lesson got over 4 million views and 57K likes, and that may indicate there is at least some value in her advice. In addition, I recommend exploring youtube further than simply this one teacher, as there are numerous free voice lessons available from as many teachers. Enough to keep you busy for hours, if not longer. Perhaps not all are the best, or the best for you, but I think it would be definitely worth your time to dig in and see what you might find. (Of course, there are also lessons that are free, and useful, but exist primarily as ads to entice viewers into purchasing further lessons, so just be aware.) Just type "voice lessons" into the search field and you'll be off and running...and singing...in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I have to tell you this:

> So I have a bit of a problem. Anytime I try to sing higher than I normally can do without going out of tune, my voice will crack and then stop. Like no sound will come out and I'm only exhaling.

Worries me.  It sounds like you're making yourself hoarse.  I'd second Rootley's advise and seek out a good voice teacher (look up Brett Manning if you'd like )

Also this is a bit concerning too:

> Anytime I try to sing with chest voice, my voice becomes very lazy and loose sounding. Like I can't hold a tune and I struggle to sing on key

That's pretty much what's known as "pulling up chest", when you sing in chest voice and try to sing too hard, you automatically fall out of pitch.

I can tell you that projecting your voice isn't so much singing loud as it's singing to be heard further away, there's a difference.  Think of a garden hose, if it's shooting water out 3 feet, but you squeeze the hose, the stream gets thinner but it also shoots out further.  Projecting your voice works the same way,  you're using the same stream of air but shooting it further , only with your diaphragm, not your throat.

Definelty get a good voice teacher, as you may wind up loosing your voice if you continue with what you're doing!  (I'm a keyboardist and a singer btw! )

Answer (score 0):

'Trying really hard' is part of the problem. Just from what you have written, I can say it is a 99% certainty that, with the best will in the world, you are forcing the voice and distorting whatever natural gift you have. Sing inside yourself at a level that feels organic and 'natural'. Seek smoothness of line and internal sensation, rather than listening to the sound you make.  Psychologically, it is **very important to you as the singer** that the listener is drawn in to what you do, rather than having your voice thrown in their faces! 
  The voice naturally needs to change register at certain points. Forcing the pure chest voice higher than nature intended is similar to trying to make a car achieve 70mph in first gear! 
 The concept of 'projection' is actually quite a dangerous one, because it creates a mental picture that is completely contrary to what the process of producing rich, resonant and SUSTAINABLE singing entails. You definitely need to work with a good professional voice teacher, preferably one who has respectable performing credentials in opera - even if that is not the music you sing, the vocal techniques of opera are the most robust and durable, because it makes the greatest demands on the human voice.
Good luck.